# How to retrieve data from one to many relations in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, one-to-many

I am making my personal website using django 1.10

Here is models of skill app:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class Skill(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def __str__(self):
        return  self.name


class Subskill(models.Model):
    skill = models.ForeignKey(Skill, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from skill.models import Skill,Subskill


# Create your views here.
def home(request):        
    skill = Skill.objects.all()
    subskill =Subskill.objects.all()    
    context = {'skills':skill,
               'subskills':subskill}
    return render(request, 'skill.html', context)
```

This is my template page:

## skill.html

```
{% block skill %}
{% for subskill in subskills %}
{{subskill.skill.name}}
{{subskill.name}}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock skill %}
```

Let assume, there is a skill named web design which has two subskill named html and css.
I want to render in view page as like as skill name and it's two child name:

**Web design**

Html

CSS

But it renders as like Web design Html Web design CSS

Please help me about this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do [realted query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) on skill itself
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects

```
# example
skill_obj = Skill.objects.all()[0]
subskills = skill_obj.subskill_set.all()
```

Or in your case

```
def home(request):        
    skills = Skill.objects.all().prefetch_related('subskill_set') # optimizing
    context = {'skills':skills}
    return render(request, 'skill.html', context)
```

In template

```
{% for skill in skills %}
    {{skill.name}}
    {% for subskill in skill.subskill_set.all %}
        {{subskill.name}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It shows error as like 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'subskill_set'

Comment: Read updated answer `skill = skill.subskil_set.all()` was meant to be applied when skill is object not queryset

Comment: Reformat a bit  {% for skill in skills %}         {{subskill.skill.name}}
    {% for subskill in skill.subskill_set.all %}

Comment: @Engr.TanbirHasan copy and paste code again. I changed it little bit.

Comment: Wow! It is working. Great Boss. You are a real rockstar. Thank you. :)